# How to fetch all google plus friends?

Tags: ios, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to fetch google plus friend list and currently I get only 100 friends. This is my current code

```
GTLQueryPlus *query =
    [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                    collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
[plusService executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
              GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
              // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
              NSArray* peopleList = peopleFeed.items;
            }
        }];
```

When I searched I found this link https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list and found that Google provides list in pages with max set of 100 so to fetch another list I would need to make use of pageToken. I couldnt find any pagetoken property in my current response. Where would I get this pagetoken and how should I make the request?

Comment: it seems, from the own documentation you've pointed, that you must get the nextPageToken and then use it as the next pageToken

Comment: there's a JSON up there showing the nextPageToken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `nextPageToken` property for the `GTLPlusPeopleFeed` object. See the comments in http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Plus/Generated/GTLPlusPeopleFeed.h

You would provide this as a parameter to the next call to `queryForPeopleListWithUserId` to get the next batch of results from the query. See the comments for http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Plus/Generated/GTLQueryPlus.h